# Нужно, чтобы при клике на кнопку открывался и пролистывался слайдер

Tags: javascript

У меня получается, что пролистываются все слайды, которые находятся на кнопках (табах).

```js
const   navList = document.querySelector('.nav-list'),
      repairSlider = document.querySelectorAll('.tabs-slider>img'),
        repairTypesNavItem = document.querySelectorAll('.repair-types-nav__item'),
        tabsSlider = document.querySelectorAll('.tabs-slider');

    const toggleTabContent = (index) => {
        for(let i = 0; i < tabsSlider.length; i++){
            if(index === i){
                repairTypesNavItem[i].classList.add('active');
                tabsSlider[i].classList.remove('hidden');
            }else{
                repairTypesNavItem[i].classList.remove('active');
                tabsSlider[i].classList.add('hidden');
            }
        }
    };

navList.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let target = e.target;
    if(target.classList.contains('repair-types-nav__item')){
        repairTypesNavItem.forEach((item, i) => {
            if(item === target){
                toggleTabContent(i);
            }
        });
    }
}); 
const sliders = () => {
    const sliderContent = document.querySelector('.repair-types-slider-wrap'),
            slider = document.querySelectorAll('.slider'),
            tabsSlider = document.querySelectorAll('.tabs-slider'),
            sliderArrow = document.querySelectorAll('.slider-arrow');
    let currentSlide = 0;

    const startSlide = () => {
        sliderArrow.forEach((elem) => {
            elem.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
                let target = e.target;
                if(target.classList.contains('slider-arrow_right') || target.classList.contains('next')){
                    slider[currentSlide].classList.remove('item-active');
                    currentSlide++;
                    if(currentSlide >= slider.length){
                        currentSlide = 0;
                    }
                    slider[currentSlide].classList.add('item-active');  
                }else if(target.classList.contains('slider-arrow_left') || target.classList.contains('prev')){
                    if(currentSlide - 1 == -1){
                    }else{
                        slider[currentSlide].classList.remove('item-active');
                        currentSlide--;
                        slider[currentSlide].classList.add('item-active');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }
    startSlide();
    };
```

```js
const repair = () => {
    const   navList = document.querySelector('.nav-list'),
      repairSlider = document.querySelectorAll('.tabs-slider>img'),
        repairTypesNavItem = document.querySelectorAll('.repair-types-nav__item'),
        tabsSlider = document.querySelectorAll('.tabs-slider');

    const toggleTabContent = (index) => {
        for(let i = 0; i < tabsSlider.length; i++){
            if(index === i){
                repairTypesNavItem[i].classList.add('active');
                tabsSlider[i].classList.remove('hidden');
            }else{
                repairTypesNavItem[i].classList.remove('active');
                tabsSlider[i].classList.add('hidden');
            }
        }
    };

navList.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    let target = e.target;
    if(target.classList.contains('repair-types-nav__item')){
        repairTypesNavItem.forEach((item, i) => {
            if(item === target){
                toggleTabContent(i);
            }
        });
    }
}); 
const sliders = () => {
    const sliderContent = document.querySelector('.repair-types-slider-wrap'),
            slider = document.querySelectorAll('.slider'),
            tabsSlider = document.querySelectorAll('.tabs-slider'),
            sliderArrow = document.querySelectorAll('.slider-arrow');
    let currentSlide = 0;

    const startSlide = () => {
        sliderArrow.forEach((elem) => {
            elem.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
                let target = e.target;
                if(target.classList.contains('slider-arrow_right') || target.classList.contains('next')){
                    slider[currentSlide].classList.remove('item-active');
                    currentSlide++;
                    if(currentSlide >= slider.length){
                        currentSlide = 0;
                    }
                    slider[currentSlide].classList.add('item-active');  
                }else if(target.classList.contains('slider-arrow_left') || target.classList.contains('prev')){
                    if(currentSlide - 1 == -1){
                    }else{
                        slider[currentSlide].classList.remove('item-active');
                        currentSlide--;
                        slider[currentSlide].classList.add('item-active');
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    }
    startSlide();
    };
    /*sliders();*/
};
repair();
```

```html
<section class="repair-types" id="repair-types">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="repair-types__inner">
                    <div class="repair-types-slider-wrap">
                        <div class="types-repair1 tabs-slider">
                            <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="img/sliders/repair/electro.jpg" alt="ремонт"></div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="img/sliders/repair/capital.jpg" alt="ремонт"></div>
                            <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="img/sliders/repair/cosmetic.jpg" alt="ремонт"></div>   
                        </div>
                        <div class="types-repair2 tabs-slider hidden">
                            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                                <div class="slider swiper-slide item-active"><img src="img/sliders/repair/cosmetic.jpg" alt="ремонт"></div>
                                <div class="slider swiper-slide"><img src="img/sliders/repair/electro.jpg" alt="ремонт"></div>    
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="types-repair3 tabs-slider hidden">
                            <div class="slider item-active"><img src="img/sliders/repair/capital.jpg" alt="ремонт"></div>
                            <div class="slider"><img src="img/sliders/repair/capital.jpg" alt="ремонт"></div>
                            <div class="slider"><img src="img/sliders/repair/cosmetic.jpg" alt="ремонт"></div>
                            <div class="slider"><img src="img/sliders/repair/cosmetic.jpg" alt="ремонт"></div>
                            <div class="slider"><img src="img/sliders/repair/cosmetic.jpg" alt="ремонт"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="types-repair4 tabs-slider hidden">
                            <div class="slider item-active"><img src="img/sliders/repair/electro.jpg" alt="ремонт"></div>
                            <div class="slider"><img src="img/sliders/repair/capital.jpg" alt="ремонт"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="types-repair5 tabs-slider hidden">
                            <div class="slider item-active"><img src="img/sliders/repair/cosmetic.jpg" alt="ремонт"></div>
                            <div class="slider"><img src="img/sliders/repair/electro.jpg" alt="ремонт"></div>
                            <div class="slider"><img src="img/sliders/repair/cosmetic.jpg" alt="ремонт"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="slider-arrow slider-arrow_left slider-repair-arrow_left" id="repair-types-arrow_left">
                            <svg class="prev"><use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#next"></use></svg>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slider-arrow slider-arrow_right slider-repair-arrow_right" id="repair-types-arrow_right">
                            <svg class="next"><use xlink:href="img/sprite.svg#next"></use></svg>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="repair-types-tab">
                        <div class="section-title repair-types-title">
                            Какие виды
                            <span>ремонта мы делаем:</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="nav-wrap nav-wrap-repair">
                            <div class="nav repair-types-nav">
                                <div class="nav-list nav-list-repair">
                                    <button type="button" class="button_o repair-types-nav__item repair-types-nav__item-1 active">
                                        Частичный ремонт
                                    </button>

                                    <button type="button" class="button_o repair-types-nav__item repair-types-nav__item-1">
                                        Косметический ремонт
                                    </button>

                                    <button type="button" class="button_o repair-types-nav__item repair-types-nav__item-1">
                                        Капитальный ремонт
                                    </button>

                                    <button type="button" class="button_o repair-types-nav__item repair-types-nav__item-1">           
                                        Евроремонт ремонт
                                    </button>

                                    <button type="button" class="button_o repair-types-nav__item repair-types-nav__item-1">        
                                        Индивидуальный ремонт
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>    
                </div>   
                
            </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: При нажатии на кнопки ничего не происходит вообще, так и должно быть?

Comment: Не совсем понятно что должно происходить, что такое `slider-arrow`, `slider-arrow_left` ... эти все элементы необходимы для решения проблемы? Сократите до минимального демо. Картинки можно вставить через сайты [site 1](https://www.fillmurray.com/) [site2](https://dummyimage.com/) если они необходимы для решения проблемы. SVG спрайты необходимы для решения проблемы?